# htaccess file - change underscores to hyphens for more than two words in url

Tags: javascript, php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to change all underscores to hyphens for my website. currently I have this code added to .htaccess file.

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule !\.(html|php)$ - [S=6]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2-$3-$4-$5-$6-$7 [E=underscores:Yes]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2-$3-$4-$5-$6 [E=underscores:Yes]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2-$3-$4-$5 [E=underscores:Yes]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2-$3-$4 [E=underscores:Yes]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2-$3 [E=underscores:Yes]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2 [E=underscores:Yes]

RewriteCond %{ENV:underscores} ^Yes$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.askapache.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However, It only works for url such as www.abc.com/about_us to www.abc.com/about-us and not for urls that have more than two words such as www.abc.com/about_us_what_do_you_mean

Can somebody help me out regarding this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than so many complex rules, you can use these two recursive rules to replace all underscore by hyphens:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule \.(html?|php)$ - [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_+([^_]*)$ http://www.askapache.com/$1-$2 [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_+(.*)$ $1-$2 [N,DPI]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, This poses same issue as Urls with large names do not get changed to hyphens such as https://test.com/front/a_b_c_d. it works for https://test.com/front/a_b though.

Comment: works fine for small url, but for longer urls now, it directs to http://www.askapache.com/a-b-c-d/.... and 404 page not found on tab. I tried changing the url  http://www.askapache.com to my url, but it still directs to http://www.askapache.com.

Comment: That is due to browser cache. Completely clear browser cache and test.