# How do I use .htaccess RewriteRule to change underscores to hyphens

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When I try that this I redirect to my site root only.

For example:

```
https://example.com/video_cat/a-respiratory/
```

I want all underscores to be replaced with `-` (hyphen) but when I try this I'm redirected to `https://example.com`

Here is my `.htaccess` configuration

```
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_(.*)$ /$1-$2 [R=301,L]
 RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301]
```

### Complete `.htaccess` file:

```
#BEGIN CORS access to staging environments

   #start start's here
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   RewriteEngine on
  #RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_+(.*)$ /$1-$2-$3 [L,NC,R=302]

  RewriteBase / 
  RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_(.*)$ /$1-$2 [R=301,L]
  RewriteRule
```

Comment: Have you cleared your browser cache? Do you have anything else in your `.htaccess` file? Any other `.htaccess` files? The directives you have posted cannot cause this, so _something else_ is triggering this redirect.

Comment: i  cleared the cache

Comment: You must have something else that is causing the redirect to root. In isolation, the directive(s) you posted should "work". (Although they are not the most efficient since they trigger an external redirect for every character substitution. And you only need one of the directives - they both do the same thing. But these issues are secondary to the erroneous redirect you are seeing.) How are you routing your URLs? I assume `/video_cat/a-respiratory/` (or `/video-cat/a-respiratory/`) does not map to a physical file/directory, so presumably you have a front-controller of some kind?

Comment: i am using WordPress , there is no directory like video-cat but it should replace underscore with hiphen that's it

Comment: "i am using WordPress" - in which case you must have a _front-controller_ and more directives in your `.htaccess` file. Please edit your question and include your entire `.htaccess` file. You probably have a conflict with your existing directives.

Comment: @MrWhite please help me to solve this i don't have directory video_cat/a-respiratory/ in my site i just want to replace the "_" with "-" but when i tried this , i am getting redirected to home page   dev.domain.com/video_categories/allergy-respiratory/ ,, this need to be replaced with "-"

Comment: i have lot of rules in .htaccess file

Comment: Please read my comments above, we cannot help without more information.

Comment: @MrWhite i have update my .htaccess file check now

Comment: A quick glance... there seems to be an error - maybe in pasting your code? At this line `<FilesMatch "\. ` ...?

Comment: @MrWhite now check it

Comment: Just to confirm, when you request `https://example.com/video-cat/a-respiratory/` directly (with hyphens) then the page is served as intended?

Comment: @MrWhite i l get redirect to https:/example.com/

Comment: @MrWhite now i am not redirecting but underscore are not replacing with dash change to this Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_+(.*)$ https://dev.domain.com/$1-$2 [N,DPI]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_+([^_]*)$ https://dev.domain.com/$1-$2 [L,R=301,NE]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess file - change underscores to hyphens for more than two words in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42143350/htaccess-file-change-underscores-to-hyphens-for-more-than-two-words-in-url)